# Adjust points based on offset angle

Tags: geometry, polygon-creation

[image]I have a centre point XY. I have a series of measurements around the point in xy offsets in centemetres from XY. I need to create a polygon of these measurements.

With the first measurement x is always = 0. Sometimes the first measurement is not due north from XY. When this is the case I have an angle describing north in relation to the first measurement, e.g. 325, if the first measurement is on an azimuth 35 degrees east of north.

How do I adjust x and y to get their "true" positions in relation to XY?

I've tried (in python):

```
angle =  math.radians( 360 - 325 ) 
newX = X + x * cos(angle)
newY = Y + y * sin(angle)
```

but things don't quite look right.[image]

Comment: The argument for trig functions is always expressed in **radians**.  325 *radians*  is equivalent to ~261 degrees.

Comment: I've edited the question so that it is hopefully clearer. At the same time I changed the radians calculation to be 360 - the azimuth, which has given better, but not quite right results.

Comment: What result do you get and why doesn't it look correct?

Comment: 360 minus azimuth isn't correct for a north-clockwise bearing (unless you also switch sine and cosine). Try 270.

Comment: I've added 2 images, 1 showing the graph with the measurements, the other showing 3 different attempts that I've mapped in QGiS - hopefully you can see the layer name on the left describing the calculations

Answer (score 1):

A quick [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) search suggests:

```
newx = x * cos(angle) − y * sin(angle)    
newy = y * cos(angle) + x * sin(angle)
```